# Subscribe meteor collection through a handlebars helper

Tags: meteor

On my quest to gain meteor knowledge, I found a new hurdle.

I was using autopublish with my application.
I registered a `Settings` collection through a helpers to have the values available globally.

```
// in settings.js
Settings = new Meteor.Collection('settings');
Settings.insert(
  {
  logo: 'Comparer Caisses Enregistreuses',
  contact: {
    human: '01 82 88 19 13',
    machine:'0440182881913'
  },
  headline: 'Comparez les meilleurs fournisseurs de Caisses!',
  tagline: "Obtenez jusqu\'à 4 devis gratuits et économisez votre temps et votre argent",
  offer: 'Economisez <span class="value">jusqu\'a 40%</span> sur votre caisses',
}
)
```

And then in `client/main.js`

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('view', function(){
    return Settings.findOne();
  });
```

I have now removed `autopublish` and I'm trying to register the collection again.

In the server folder:

```
  // server/publication.js
  Meteor.publish('settings', function(){
    return Settings.findOne();
    // or should it be `return settings` so that I can call `.findOne()` in my helper
  });
```

In the client folder:

```
// client/main.js
  Meteor.subscribe('settings');

  Handlebars.registerHelper('view', function(){
    // here nothing work
    // return settings;
    // return Settings.findOne();
    // not sure how to call the publication
  });
```

Is there a way to subscribe to a publication through a helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Meteor.publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) is supposed to be used in server-side code, not on the client.

**EDIT**

Your updated code:

```
  // server/publication.js
  Meteor.publish('settings', function(){
    return Settings.findOne();
    // or should it be `return settings` so that I can call `.findOne()` in my helper
  });
```

As you already pointed out, it should be `return Settings.find()` because the function given as a second parameter to `Meteor.publish` should return a single or multiple cursors (not a single document which is returned by `findOne()`).

Comment: Thanks, I was just reading about that. I moved the publish code in the server folder. But now when I try to subscribe the collection through the `handlebars.registerHelper` everything crash.

Comment: So in publication.js it should be `return Settings.find()`, then in client/main.js `meteor.subscribe('settings')`? What I don't understand is how to then make settings available globally through the handlebars helper. Are published collection available globally by default?

Comment: Correct. Not sure if I understand the second question. `Settings = new Meteor.Collection('settings');` (which is loaded on the server and the client) makes the returned subscription handle assigned to `Settings` globally available in JS. `Handlebars.registerHelper('view', function(){...});` registers a global template helper which can be accessed in any template using `{{view}}` (in your HTML code). In this template helper you can of course use `Settings` .

Comment: Since you return `Settings.findOne()` in your template helper you can e.g. use `{{view.logo}}`.

Comment: Ok got it now. I thought that I had to change the call in the handlebars helper to `settings` instead of `Settings`. The moral of the story is don't change anything :). Thanks for your help.

Comment: As a side note — I don't really need it now — if i want to make sure that nobody can modify the settings on the fly, removing `autopublish` is not enough I guess. I need user authentication?

Comment: If you want to decide which data is published by the server (and which is not) you need to remove `autopublish`. This step is indepent from setting up rules to decide who is allowed to do what with a published collection. For this you would need to remove the `insecure` package and set up specific `allow` and/or `deny` rules. In those rules you would typically check with which user you are dealing with. So, yes, you would need user authentication.